Não consigo rodar java
Olá!
Por que aparece essa mensagem no meu vscode quando estou tentando rodar java "A variável java.jdt.ls.java.home definida nas configurações do Visual Studio Code aponta para uma pasta ausente ou inacessível (c:\Program Files\17.0.11)"?
Essas são as minhas variáveis de ambiente:variaveis de ambiente

Olá!
De acordo com o exposto na imagem que você enviou, referente à configuração das variáveis de ambiente, você criou uma variável de ambiente com o nome JAVA-HOME (perceba o hífen) quando, aparentemente, pretendia denominá-la JAVA_HOME (com underscore).
Há outras maneiras de configurar a versão da JDK a ser usada, como explicado na documentação do Visual Studio Code e na página da extensão java para VS Code fornecida pela Red Hat. Contudo, acredito que renomeando de JAVA-HOME para JAVA_HOME seu problema será resolvido.
